# Cannot find a declaration file in index.ts that exports typescript and javascript components

Tags: typescript, installation, type-declaration

I am beginning to convert design system components into Typescript but am struggling to setup our index.ts file.

I keep getting `Could not find a declaration file for module xxx. Implicitly has 'any' type`.

Our current file structure is:

```
- index.ts
- components
   - Button.tsx
   - Input.jsx
   - Icon.jsx
```

The index.ts file looks like:

```
export * from './components/Button' // no error
export * from './components/Input' // cannot find declaration
export * from './components/Icon' // cannot find declaration
```

Note that I have converted the Button to .tsx already, but won't be able to get to the other components until sometime in the future.

I have created a global `.d.ts` file for the design system components and can import them from other parts of the application without getting errors, but the index.ts file gives off the declaration file error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your tsconfig.json but generally, you need to declare non-typescript file types as a module. Example:

```
declare module "*.jsx" { }
```

In the specific case of `.jsx` files, you can specify the [`--jsxFactory`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsxFactory) option. In your tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Add the following:
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
    },
}
```

See also, [Typescript Documentation - JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html).

> Configuring JSX
> There are multiple compiler flags which can be used to customize your JSX, which work as both a compiler flag and via inline per-file pragmas. To learn more see their tsconfig reference pages:
>
> - [`jsxFactory`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsxFactory)
> - [`jsxFragmentFactory`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsxFragmentFactory)
> - [`jsxImportSource`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsxImportSource)